# jQuery でマウスホバー時に border を出したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hoverしたときにspanタグにborderを出したいのですが上手くいきません。
どうすればうまくいきますか？

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/xxx.html"><span class="linear">xxx</span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/xxx.html"><span class="linear">xxx</span></a></li>
</ul>



$(".nav-item").hover(function(){
      $("this").find('span').css('border-bottom', ' 1px solid #fff');
    }, function() {
      $("this").find('span').css('border-bottom', ' 1px solid #ccc');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

ここで利用しているthisはテキストではなくて
[thisキーワード](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)になります。
そのためダブルクォーテーションでくくってはだめです。

```js
$(".nav-item").hover(function(){
      $(this).find('span').css('border-bottom', ' 1px solid #fff');
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('span').css('border-bottom', ' 1px solid #ccc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/xxx.html"><span class="linear">xxx</span></a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="navbar-link" href="/xxx.html"><span class="linear">xxx</span></a></li>
</ul>
```